# Is it possible copy and save bootloader using CLI telnet commands?

Tags: binary-analysis, linux, memory, embedded, flash

I need get copy of original Bootloader from device running embedded Linux. Is it possible copy and save bootloader using CLI telnet commands? I have full access to CLI interface. Is there way copy Bootloader binary from memory and save it?

```
=> printenv
...
update_uboot=tftpboot 0x80000100 u-boot.bin && protect off 0x48000000 +${filesize} && erase 0x48000000 +${filesize} && sleep ${sdelay} && cp.b ${fileaddr} 0x48000000 ${filesize} && protect on 0x48000000 +${filesize}
...

ubootpartsize=0x20000

mtdinfo=0x20000(U-Boot)ro
mtdparts=spansion:0x20000(U-Boot)ro

5 cmdlinepart partitions found on MTD device spansion
partitions[0] = {.name = U-Boot, .offset = 0x00000000,.size = 0x00020000 (128K) }

0x00000000-0x00020000 : "U-Boot"
```

EDIT: netcat is not present in Busybox on embedded device.

```
BusyBox v1.19.2 built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
# help
Built-in commands:
------------------
        . : [ [[ bg break cd chdir continue echo eval exec exit export
        false fg getopts hash help jobs kill local printf pwd read readonly
        return set shift source test times trap true type ulimit umask
        unset wait
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bootloader is in the flash, so you have to dump it first by using:

```
dd if=/dev/mtd0 of=/tmp/mtd0
```

or

```
nandump -of /tmp/mtd0 /dev/mtd0
```

After it you have to copy to an SD card, USB device or send via netcat (`nc`) to a socket. Of course you can do it in one step also.

EDIT

You can send files via netcat with 2 easy steps.

1. Start netcat in your PC in listening mode to receive data and save
   the data to a file

   `nc -l -p 1337 >mtd0.bin`
2. Start netcat in the embedded device to send the data to your PC

   `nc ip_address 1337 </tmp/mtd0`

Comment: There is no SD card and no USB on device: how to send dump via netcat?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Can be used tftp for this as well?

Comment: You can use tftp also, or wget, curl, ftp and other tools as well, but I think netcat is the easiest and most common tool you may have in an embedded linux.

Comment: In case I am facing a problem with netcat implementation, how to dump bootloader raw data to the telnet screen?(then copy and save output as binary)

Comment: I don't understand the problem, you dump the bootloader data to a file and then send it to the netcat with file redirection. You don't dump it to the screen.

Comment: I just mean when netcat method not work (for any reason), get dump from screen, as a last resort.

Comment: You can, but it slow and you have to convert it somehow to display non-ascii characters, e.g. base64 or hex

Answer (score 1):

Please try https://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html
And also, read about kermit, xmodem, ymodem and zmodem protocols - these are file transfer protocols over serial lines.

U-boot has a support to receive files with "loady" command. We use it together with `lsz` command from `lrzsz` package, to update the bootloader.
I cannot see any support for sending files, but with good understanding of the *modem protocol, you could emulate proper string to activate minicom's file transfer and send whole file to your computer.

```
u-boot => help loady
loady - load binary file over serial line (ymodem mode)

Usage:
loady [ off ] [ baud ]
- load binary file over serial line with offset 'off' and baudrate 'baud'
```

The second solution might be enabling minicom's logging to file, print the whole memory region with u-boot's `md` command, and then parse the log file with a script to convert from ascii to real bytes.

Comment: `loady`(ymodem) and `loadb`implemented in U-boot allow transfer files only in one direction - from computer to the device RAM address.

Answer (score 0):

dd and netcat should work just fine.

If any problem with that, try doing an hexdump to stdout

```
hexdump -C -n 64 /dev/mtdblock0 > bootloader.bin
```

But needs a reverse shell on the target, like:

```
nc.exe [local IP] [port] -e cmd.exe
```

(cmd.exe is for MS windows, /bin/sh on linux)